# Disable ignoring of hyphen for sorting in Windows 10 File Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, sorting

In the Windows 10 **File Explorer**, the hyphen (and apostrophe?) characters are ignored for the purposes of sorting file or directory/folder names. For example:

[image]

Does anybody know how to disable this behavior?

It is affected by neither the registry setting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\​CurrentVersion\​Policies\​Explorer\​NoStrCmpLogical` nor the equivalent **Group Policy** setting "Turn off numerical sorting in Windows Explorer".

Comment: How do you want it to sort (using your example) if the hyphen is **not** ignored?

Comment: @DavidPostill Simply like any other character, by its numerical value, which is `45` / `0x2D` / `\u002D` etc. I can't fathom what's so hard about providing an option for the simplest possible case-insensitive ordinal sort, which is just by `UTF-16` character value: For the example, this means:  `-`, `-A`, `A`. As one would expect from *any* sort (and *unlike* the image above) all "first" characters are grouped together.

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible.

Comment: A correction, my previous comment should read "...simplest possible case-*sensitive* ordinal sort..." That is, where 'A' and 'a' are considered distinct.

Comment: For what it's worth, note that you also have `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Currentversion\Policies\Explorer\NoStrCmpLogical`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignoring the hyphen/dash is a "feature" that was added to Windows Explorer at the
same time as numerical sorting.
However, unlike numerical sorting, this is not controlled by any registry entry,
but is rather hard-coded into Explorer.

This cannot even be corrected by an extension, since Microsoft has
sharply curtailed their use in Explorer since after Windows XP.
Not even new
[Column Handlers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/lwef/column-handlers)
are allowed.
Only adding a custom property tab by using an extension is still supported.

The only solution is to use an alternative third-party product.
The behavior of Windows Explorer itself cannot be modified.

See the article
[Best Free File Manager](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-file-manager.htm)
for a list and reviews of such products, ranked by usability features,
and also [Altap Salamander Freeware](https://www.altap.cz/).

Comment: How appalling. Can you please mention how you know this information to be true?

Comment: See in the above article of "Creating Column Handlers" link : "This feature is supported only under Windows XP or earlier".